# Getting 'narrowSymbol' for 'currencyDisplay' is outside of valid range error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, internet-explorer

I'm getting this error in IE 20H2

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "RangeError: Option value 'narrowSymbol' for 'currencyDisplay' is outside of valid range. Expected: ['code', 'symbol', 'name']"

and I'm not sure how to solve it.

By the looks of it, it has to do with my `axios.post()` method.
Here is the method

```
axios.post(`/api/product/${this.product.id}/statement`, {
    start: this.startDate,
    end: this.endDate
}).then(response => {
    this.statement = response.data.statement
});
```

It seems to be coming from `this.statement = response.data.statement` because when I comment it out I don't get the error.

**UPDATE**

I found that it might have to do with this line of code in my app.js

```
Vue.filter('rands', function(val){
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { 
        style: 'currency', 
        'currency': 'GBP', 
        currencyDisplay: 'narrowSymbol'
    }).format(Number(val));
});
```

but I'm still not sure how to solve it

Comment: Hi, is there any update about the issue? Is my answer below helpful to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is that IE does not support `currencyDisplay` option. You can refer to [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#browser_compatibility).

You can add the following [polyfill](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-numberformat/#via-polyfillio) to fix the issue:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.NumberFormat,Intl.NumberFormat.~locale.en,Intl.PluralRules.~locale.en"></script>
```